# Tidying column names into variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I have a very messy dataset from a survey in which each check box is an indicator variable.  So instead of having gender (or race) as a variable with M/F as the entry there is a gender_m and a gender_f column with an indicator.

Simplified example:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~gender_m, ~gender_f,
  #--|----------|---------
  1L , 0        , 1,
  2L , 1        , 0,
  3L , 0        , 0,
  4L , 1        , 1
  )
```

What I want as output is:

```
  result <- tribble(
    ~id, ~gender,
    #--|----------
  1L , 'f',
  2L , 'm',
  3L , 'Missing',
  4L , 'More than 1 selected'
)
```

For something like gender where there are only 2 columns it's easy enough to hard code things, but I'm trying to make it as generic as possible since things like race (or programming languages you use) have multiple possibilities.

I have a nearly a thousand columns but less than 20 actual variables. all the columns are of the form `<variable_name>_<potential_value>`.

I'm sure I'm missing some tidy function that does this but my googlefu seems to be weak today.

Comment: The "missing" and "more than 1 selected" make this pretty specialized - I don't think you're failing to find any function that exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of the `tidy` functions work better in columns than rows, so if you convert to long this becomes a bit easier:

```
df_long = df %>%
    gather(Item, Response, starts_with("gender"))

cleaned = df_long %>%
    mutate(Item = str_match(Item, "(.*)_(.*)")[, 3]) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(RespCleaned = case_when(
        sum(Response) == 0 ~ "Missing",
        sum(Response) == 1 ~ Item[Response == 1][1],
        sum(Response) > 1 ~ "More than 1 selected"
    ))

df = df %>% left_join(cleaned, by = "id")
```

If you have lots of items with these kinds of 0/1 indicators for responses, using the sum of responses should generalize to items with more than 2 options. You would just need to replace `starts_with("gender")` with another selector than picks out the relevant columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base approach (except for `stringr`). Should generalize nicely to similar cases and be easy to put into a function. As-is, it can operate on your whole data frame with the 20 variables in 1000 columns.

```
library(stringr)
sep = "_"
vars = unique(na.omit(str_extract(names(df), ".*(?=_)")))

for (i in seq_along(vars)) {
    these_vars = names(df)[str_detect(names(df), paste0("^", vars[i]))]
    result = character(nrow(df))
    rs = rowSums(df[these_vars])
    result[rs == 0] = "mising"
    result[rs > 1] = "more than 1 selected"
    result[rs == 1] = these_vars[apply(df[rs == 1, these_vars] == 1, 1, which)]
    df[i] = result
}

df
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#      id gender_m gender_f               gender
#   <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>                <chr>
# 1     1        0        1             gender_f
# 2     2        1        0             gender_m
# 3     3        0        0               mising
# 4     4        1        1 more than 1 selected
```